# calculate login logout time in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, group-by, gaps-and-islands

I have a table structure like this

[image: x]

Time capture in a single column on basis of the event. But I required one complete event in a single row.

Required data like this:

[image: y]

Comment: why not use session instead of mysql? You can set this thing in session rather then making it complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this as a gaps-and-islands problem.

Assuming that you are running MySQL 8.0, you can define the groups with a window sum that increases by `1` everytime a `'LOGIN'` event is seen for a given user:

```
select 
    user,
    min(event_date) login,
    min(case when event = 'LOGOUT' then event_date END) logout,
    timediff(min(case when event = 'LOGOUT' then event_date END), min(event_date)) total_time
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        sum(case when event = 'LOGIN' then 1 else 0 end) 
            over(partition by user order by event_date) grp
    from mytable t
) t
group by user, grp
order by user, login
```

Note that `timediff()` handles durations that do not exceed about 838 hours. Otherwise, you need to use `timestampdiff()` or the-like.